# Unusually large value for statistic in wilcoxon test in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am running a wilcoxon test on a dataset of the mean heartrate per person before and after an experiment. There are about 62 people participating.

I run:

```
statistic, p-value = wilcoxon(dataBefore - dataAfter)
```

The p-value is 0.0005 but the statistic is 498. That seems like an unusually large number. I have noticed some unclarity as to what is returned here. I thought scipy used a t-test, but I have also seen people store this as a z-statistic. What is it returning?

The manual doesn't make much sense to me: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html It says: 
"statistic : float -- The sum of the ranks of the differences above or below zero, whichever is smaller."
But this doesn't make much sense to me. Is this a value people typically report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wilcoxon signed-rank test is used with either test statistic *W* or test statistic *T*.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) for details of the calculations of *W* and *T*, including an example.  `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` calculates *T*.  (As does R, but it calls the statistic *V*.)  For *N* = 62, the maximum possible value for *W* is 1+2+...+62 = 1953, and the maximum possible value for *T* is half that, so your *T* = 498 is fine.

Note that the Wilcoxon *T* is **not** the *t* from Student's t-test.  But a paired t-test may be usable as an alternative to Wilcoxon in your case if the before-after differences pass normality, see, e.g., GraphPad's [checklist](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_checklist_pairedt.htm).

Here an example with artificial heart-rate data, with Wilcoxon *p*-value and *T* similar to your case:

```
import scipy.stats as st, numpy as np

# example data with 63 before-after values  
before = np.arange(50, 70, 0.32)
after = np.arange(46.5, 76.5, 0.48)

print st.wilcoxon(before, after)
print st.ttest_rel(before, after)
```

The output is

```
WilcoxonResult(statistic=506.0, pvalue=0.00058875122425830928)
Ttest_relResult(statistic=-3.9512409047662991, pvalue=0.00020172580202906966)
```

The before-after differences in this example are uniformly distributed, so not very normal, so the Wilcoxon test would be the better choice.